# Making photo album in a gallery system with laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, gallery

I want to make a gallery system in laravel 5.5. So that every time i upload photos it shows in a different album with 1st photo and title that i uploaded. And after clicking to that album shows the other photos of that album. How can i do it?

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: Can you be more specific? Any code to show?

Comment: Sorry, but i am stuck in the concept of how to do it. I thought it would be great if i store the array of images in a single row in database. But i couldn't find how to do it? Can you help me? Is there other way to do it? @sg7

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here is a good example for you :
https://www.dunebook.com/tutorial-creating-a-photo-gallery-system-with-laravel/

Comment: Not the link content is the problem. Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Manke two database named gallery and photos. It will be something like this:

Gallery:
id
name
description
timestamp
cover_image
more columns.....

Photo model:
id
gallery_id
image
name
more columns.....

Save gallery and then upload multiple files in photo table with one to many relationship

Comment: Here is a good example :
https://www.dunebook.com/tutorial-creating-a-photo-gallery-system-with-laravel/